# Dynamics 365: is it required to provide terms of service and privacy statement links for all apps?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

We are developing our proprietary web application (ASP.NET) and need to integrate/sync with D365's database such as Accounts, Contacts etc. Before we were using SOAP and later it was recommended by Microsoft to use Web API from the four links below.

Our integration is done via code and there is no interface. It is only for web app, not mobile app. The kind of integration would be when adding a new account from Dynamics 365, it will add an account in a database of our proprietary app's database. Also, when adding a new contact in the database of our proprietary app's database, it will add the same contact in Dynamics 365's database.

Last week we received an email from Microsoft about adding Term of Services and Privacy Statement on your apps registered in Azure which we had to in order to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 via Web API. https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2018/02/22/heads-up-for-app-devs-updates-coming-april-2nd-to-our-user-consent-screen/

My questions are:

1. Do I need to provide those two links for what I use?
2. Is connecting Dynamics 365 via Web API the right approach to connect/integrate our app's database with Dynamics 365's database based on scenarios I mentioned above?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608055.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602917.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Should be [related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/gdpr/) to General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR). You may need to show the consent page before collecting contact/account details in your web app, so users can accept/opt out of data input in your app/database.
2. Two way sync between external app/db and Dynamics 365 using webapi is the [best approach.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx) That’s why MS came up with this REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. For #1, we just integrated D365 with our own proprietary web application. The only users are our employees. We do not sell the application. With that, do we still need to provide Terms of Use and Privacy Statement?

Comment: @SompopCharusaengrit oh that depends on your company policy.